# Java - File not found exception - shared location is missing a slash

Tags: java, java-8

I have a single liner code "Hello World" that I am executing, however it is failing every time I try to execute it.

From the looks, the shared drive location is missing a slash "/", I am just not sure where to explicitly declare or set this up. I have combed through the project settings but to no avail.

Or if there is something else I am missing, pls help.

I am a noob in Java so apologies in advance.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Below is the error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) \sgrau999bab01.ocean.corp.xyz.com\lllaaabbb$\.IdeaIC13\system\compile-server\helloworld_edf69b40\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \sgrau999bab01.ocean.corp.xyz.com\lllaaabbb$\.IdeaIC13\system\compile-server\helloworld_edf69b40\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:339)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:323)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:76)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:31)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:110)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The output expected is a simple print of the text "Hello World"

Answer (score 1):

`sgrau999bab01.ocean.corp.xyz.com` looks like a set of nested packages. You can access package content using **'.'** notation in Java but to read files we have to provide the folder path (using '/' or '\')

Can you try replacing

`\sgrau999bab01.ocean.corp.xyz.com\lllaaabbb$\.IdeaIC13\system\compile-server\helloworld_edf69b40\timestamps\data`

with

`\sgrau999bab01\ocean\corp\xyz\com\lllaaabbb$\.IdeaIC13\system\compile-server\helloworld_edf69b40\timestamps\data`

and check if it works?
I am not sure of the premise of your question and looks like you could add a few details about where is the file being read from.

P.S. I would have mentioned this as a comment but I don't have the privilege to do so. Apologies.

Comment: Hi Roy, where can I edit this? Can you pls direct me?

Comment: Hi Lucas! 

It seems to be an IDE issue rather than a java issue. Unfortunately I am not too familiar with IntelliJ. You can visit the IntelliJ support forums for help on this. I just randomly googled your issue and this is one of the links I found : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000661730-lots-of-errors-trying-to-run-a-simple-hello-world-output-     

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using backslashes as file path separators is that sometimes they lead to unintended characters.  For example, the file path:

```
String path = "some\npath";
```

actually has a newline character in it.  One simple way to avoid this problem is to just use forward slashes instead:

```
/sgrau999bab01.ocean.corp.xyz.com/lllaaabbb$/.IdeaIC13/system/compile-server/helloworld_edf69b40/timestamps/data
```

Comment: Hi Tim, the confusion really is where to set it?

Comment: I assumed you were controlling this yourself.

Comment: Hi Tim, pls consider me as Jon Snow on this one, I know nothing on Java setup. I just want to know where do I explicitly perform the replacement of backslash to forward slash, thank you.